# How can quickly add two bytes into a bytes array?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the best method to add two bytes into a existing bytes array?

Should I use `Array.Copy`?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Are you asking about increasing the number of elements in the array? Where do you want to "add" the two bytes?

Comment: Given the meaning of "Add" in the `ICollection` interface, the answer to you question is no.  You cannot increase the size of an array; you can only replace it with a different, larger array (as user1501472 suggests).  If you need the same object to grow, you should use a List, as user1501472 suggests in a separate answer.

Comment: If this is just one time operation, then use Array.Copy(). If it is repetitive, use List.

Comment: @Kelvin Follow up: if this question is answered, please either choose one of the answers or update the question to share your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is an interesting subject. I've made a microbenchmark and, yes, the fastest way is using `Array.Copy`.

Check this out: [Prepend to a C# Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402238/prepend-to-a-c-sharp-array/11402865#11402865)

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Use a List instead of a byte[]; it will provide the flexibility and it is good performance wise

```
List<byte> l1 = new List<byte>() { 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12 };  
List<byte> l2 = new List<byte> { 8, 9 };
l1.InsertRange(3, l2);
```

Then if you need to go back to a byte[] for whatever reason you can call...

```
l1.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

or else

```
byte[] newArray = new byte[theArray.Length + 1];  
theArray.CopyTo(newArray, 1);  
newArray[0] = theNewByte;  
theArray = newArray;
```

Comment: You should probably combine this with your other answer. "or else" doesn't always make sense as your two answers can appear in any order (they are not sorted by when they were written).

Comment: actually i meant to add the comment for my 1st post, but added another post by mistake.

Comment: @user1501472 then you can edit your first answer to add the content of your second answer to it, and then delete the second answer.