# Adding column to string array

Tags: c#

I have a string array with 125 columns:

```
string[] arrColumns = null;
...populate array here
field0 = arrColumns[0];
field1 = arrColumns[1];
...etc to 124
...modify array here to add a new column to the beginning of the string array
```

I need to add a new column to the beginning of the array.

So that arrColumns[0] is moved to arrColumns[1]; etc
And then I will have a new column arrColumns[0] to add data into.
Can this be done easily in C#?  Thanks before hand.

Comment: Sounds like you want a `List<string>` instead of a `string[]`... then you can insert wherever you like.

Comment: Here's an existing answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402238/prepend-to-a-c-sharp-array

Comment: The easiest way would be to iterate over all the fields in reverse (so from 124 to 0), move them by 1 (so from 125 to 1), then add your new column to arrColumn[0]. Or you can use array manipulation to create a new array, define arrColumns[0], then append your old array.

Answer (score 2):

The approach closest to what you are describing is to use the `Array.Copy` method:

```
string[] arrColumns = new string[1024];
string[] newArray = new string[arrColumns.Length + 1];

Array.Copy(arrColumns, 0, newArray, 1, arrColumns.Length);
newArray[0] = "Hello, world!
```

This is a little long winded, especially if you keep doing this. A better option is to not worry about the details of copying and inserting a value in the first position, by using a `List<T>` and go from there.

There are 3 options to improve this:

1. Use a `List<T>` with a capacity
2. Use a `List<T>` with the original array
3. Create a `List<T>` from the existing array

#### Use a `List<T>` with a capacity

Use the `List<string>` that accepts a capacity in the constructor, so that you give it a heads up (where possible) on the size to create.

It will then allocate the initial size internally, but still know the number of items stored in the `.Count`, rather than the `.Capacity`. It is also dynamically expanding:

```
List<string> listOfColumns = new List<string>(1024); // Set initial capacity
listOfColumns.Add( .... );
```

#### Use a `List<T>` with the original array

Another alternative is to just pass the array directly into the constructor, and you can use the overload to pass an existing array in:

```
List<string> listOfColumns = new List<string>(arrColumns);
```

#### Create a `List<T>` from the existing array

Use the System.Linq extension to create a `List<T>` automatically:

```
List<string> listOfColumns = arrColumns.ToList();
```

---

Then you can insert an item into the beginning of the list.

```
listOfColumns.Insert(0, "Hello, World!");
```

To get the data as an array, use the [`.ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
string[] arrColumns = listOfColumns.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could copy to a `List<string>`...

```
string[] strArray = new string[99];
strArray[0] = "1";
strArray[1] = "2";
strArray[2] = "3";

var strList = new List<string>();
strList.Add("0");
strList.AddRange(strArray.Where(a => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a)));
```

This will create a new list with whatever you add at the first position, and then add the records from the array where the element isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

If it should be an array you can use this

```
// Create a temporary array
string[] tmp = (string[])arrColumns.Clone();

// Take the first items and copy to temp
arrColumns.Take(arrColumns.Length-1).ToArray().CopyTo(tmp, 1);

// Add new element at position 0
tmp[0] = "New";

// Copy back
tmp.CopyTo(arrColumns);
```

This will shift your data one position to the end and delete the last entry. The size of the array will not change.