# Merging 2 json values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a JSON body

```
{
  "id": "1581fbd2-c045-4162-9f4c-ddbca6a88d61",
  "content": "VONP//content in base64",
  "title": "ProfileImage",
  "type": "image/jpeg",
  "created": "2023-08-03T18:55:46.736405+03:00"
}
```

I want `type` to be inside `content` like this

```
{
  "content": "image/jpeg//content in base64",
  "type": "image/jpeg"
}
```

additional code:

I have a model for my json

```
public class MediaModelResponse
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  public byte[] Content { get; set; }

  public string Title { get; set; }

  public string Type { get; set; }

  public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

can't figure out the correct way to do this

Comment: As with all tasks, break it down. You have `content`, which is a byte array. So you'll need to convert the `type` string to a byte array. We have many questions [on how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16072709/215552). Then you'd need to prepend that to the existing array. Again [we've been over that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402238/prepend-to-a-c-sharp-array).

Comment: None of the ostensible JSON examples are valid JSON, unless you surround them with curlies. If, however, you do that and use an automatic formatter (try, e.g. https://jsonlint.com), nothing is nested inside anything else. Please edit the question so that it presents a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can probably delete the service and controller code as well. ATM at least, I don't see how that code sheds any light on the problem, or what you've tried to address it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can I do all the necessary manipulations inside the controller alone?
@HereticMonkey

Comment: Please don't delete your comments and readd them to ping me again. It is very rude, akin to calling someone every five minutes to see if they got your email. Besides, I linked to questions whose answers should answer any questions you have. Where you do the manipulations is up to you.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sorry, just wasnt sure i used @ correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets try and put some code together for this task.

Firstly lets assume we have our Model in this variable...
Then taking the articles posted.
[Converting string to byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp)
[Prepend to a C# Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402238/prepend-to-a-c-sharp-array)
Gives you something like this..

```
var MyMediaResponse = new MediaModelResponse();
//populate MyMediaResponse

byte[] TypeBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(MyMediaResponse.Type);

var newContent = MyMediaResponse.Content.Prepend(TypeBytes);

var obj = new 
{
    Id = MyMediaResponse.Id ,
    Content = newContent ,
    Title = MyMediaResponse.Title,
    Created = MyMediaResponse.Created
};
var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
```

Something like this should work (in theory)